# Is Authorization not yet supported for ADFS 2016?

Tags: asp.net-core, adfs

I have followed the instructions at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593305.aspx to set up ADFS on Windows Server 2016 for OpenID Connect.  I then configured an ASPNET Core application to authenticate with this server.  Sign works fine except that I had to add a redirect URI that included "/signin-oidc" to get it to recognize my app.

The problem I am having is that I have no claims for the users group in ad and cannot use the authorize attribute with parameters.  When an action is called that uses this attribute the browser is redirected to the adfs endpoint but an error is returned that the request could not be completed.  Am I doing something wrong or is ADFS not an option for this scenario?

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that but that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3):

The team of ASP.NET recommends to use IdentityServer https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4 for ASP.NET Core 1.
This project is well known, very stable and organized by Dominick Baier, a well known security guy and 11 times Microsoft MVP for ASP.NET

Comment: Is it still recommended for ASP.NET 2.0? I know there has been changes in authentication in this new version. BTW, I want to authenticate against my company's Active Directory (AD on-premises) and I understand this is what IdentifyServer4 does. Am I wrong?

Comment: @SuperJMN yes, it still is.